# Python urllib2 giving "network unreachable error" if the URL is https

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, urllib2

I am trying to fetch some urls using urllib2 library.

```
a = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
ret = a.read()
```

Code above is working fine, and giving expected result. But when I make the url https, it gives "network unreachable" error

```
a = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com")
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Is there any problem with ssl? My python version is Python2.6.5. I am also behind an academic proxy server. I have the settings in bash file. Anyway, since http is opening proxy shouldn't be the problem here.

Comment: It works for me. I'm using 2.7.3

Comment: I don't have any problem opening "https"..

Comment: http://github.com is giving the same error in this case, as it is redirecting to https.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the issue in cases like this is the proxy you are behind having an out of date or untrusted SSL certificate. urllib is fussier than most browsers when it comes to SSL and this is why you might be getting this error.

Comment: I am behind a Big Academic Organization proxy. SSL certificate is not in my hands. So is there anyway I can get around this error.

Comment: *Warning HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.* - Fussier how? It doesn't perform any certificate verification - From Docs: `Warning HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.`

Comment: it may not validate the cert, but if a middleman proxy mishandles your request it will just fail, rather than retry or try workarounds. I came across this sort of thing today when I was using fiddler to inspect a https request I was making.

Answer (score 1):

The http url didn't give error because http_proxy variable was set already. By setting https_proxy the above error disappears.

```
export http_proxy = "http://{proxy-address}"
```

Set samething for https_proxy

```
export https_proxy = "http://{proxy-address}"
```